# Touch sensitivity problem

Tags: touchscreen

I'm using glaxy grand (I9083). I was facing this touch problem. For example, if i touch and hold letter 'e' on my keyboard to enter number 3, it will type bunch of letter e's (eeeeee). First I thought it was some software problem(touch driver). But today I found out that if I remove the back cover and use the phone, problem goes away. Weird right?. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Probably not the issue but make sure your hands and the screen are both clean. This happens to me if i get certain substances on my fingers and then subsequently on the screen

Comment: Nope that's not it. If I remove the back cover, it perfectly works. And then I put it back on, problem comes again

Comment: Tell us more about this cover. What kind is it, and how does it attach?

Comment: It's just the battery cover that comes with the phoone (battery cover)

Comment: It's a plastic flip cover

Comment: It could be they somehow the battery is interfering with the screen when it gets pressed farther into the office by the case. How? I'm really don't know.

Comment: Yes that might be the case. When I loosen up the cover it works ok

Comment: Try putting a paper shim behind the battery (without blocking the contacts on the phone or battery, of course). That might create enough space to prevent the interference. I've experienced similar symptoms while a phone is charging, but that's a slightly different situation. Maybe your phone has a slight manufacturing defect? It could be the cover, the battery, or an internal component that's not quite properly shielded.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of static charge accumulated during charging. Use the stock charger if currently not using also there are many tips to remove that static charge off your screen. Try those and tell us.

Answer (score -1):

Ivcode ,this maybe a solution for your problem.

First of all ,try to upgrade your android.

Second,go to settings>my device>display.

There must be an option at bottom named 'Increase touch sensitivity'.

Tick it and you are done!

If it helped then please reply, if not then let me know what happened.